# How to compile java source from custom ide

Tags: java, ide, compilation, interpreter

I am making an interpreted language with java......and am also making an IDE for it. I want to know how to compile java source from my IDE and have it run on a console. I have created a simple console window. But how do i compile java source from my simple IDE and route its output to my console window?

The Interpreted language is interpreted by an interpreter i created and it then creates a java source that needs to be compiled.

Comment: Too ambitious?  I do not think that should be in ANY developers vocabulary...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface from the JDK. Read the linked documentation to get an elaborate example of how to use it.

As to running the resulting code, you use the [`Tool`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/Tool.html) class.

In general: Check out the `javax.tools` package in the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get the syntax right, you would want to compile it using `javac` .  Now choosing which implementation of the JVM to use is another issue as not everything lines up so "nicely"